# How to fetch data from a xml string without a xml tag- C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, xml, xpath

I have one class like below

```
namespace CustomerData
  {
   [Serializable]
  public class Customer
    { 
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "u_additional_DeskNumber ")]
    public string DeskNumber { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "u_additional_customerid")]
     public string CustomerID{ get; set; }
   }
  }
```

I am fetching data from Database and mapping to this Customer class. From Database DeskNumber will return in either following format.Db data type for desknumber is nvarchar

**Format 1.**

```
   <AdditionalInfo><Number>164</Number></AdditionalInfo>
```

**Format2**

```
 <AdditionalInfo><Code>GLW51</Code><LangCode>GLW51</LangCode><TzCode>GLW51</TzCode></AdditionalInfo>
```

If data returns Format1 ,i need to return value under Number tag (ie .164).Value under Number tag will be different at different time. If the value returned from databse is in any other format other than Format 1,then value should set as blank.

I am using following generic method for Mappaing data reader to Corresponding Classes

```
     private static List<T> MapDataToEntity<T>(IDataReader dr) where T : new()
    {
        Type businessEntityType = typeof(T);
        List<T> entitys = new List<T>();
        Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = businessEntityType.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo info in properties)
        {
            hashtable[info.Name.ToUpper()] = info;
        }

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            T newObject = new T();
            for (int index = 0; index < dr.FieldCount; index++)
            {
                PropertyInfo info = (PropertyInfo)
                                    hashtable[dr.GetName(index).ToUpper()];
                if ((info != null) && info.CanWrite)
                {
                    info.SetValue(newObject, dr.GetValue(index), null);
                }
            }
            entitys.Add(newObject);
        }

        dr.Close();
        return entitys;
    }
```

So i have following questions,

1.How can i find value under Number tag from this below string

```
 <AdditionalInfo><Number>164</Number></AdditionalInfo>
```

2. How to add a logic that if it is not in above format(ie Format1),then it should blank.

3.Where i need to put this logic,In Set Method of DeskNumber ??

Can anyone plese suggest a  better approach with a sample code

Comment: Your second piece of XML is invalid, and neither piece of XML seems to relate to the properties int he sample class you've given. You've then presented code which doesn't appear to use XML at all. All of this makes the question very hard to follow. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit the question to be a *lot* clearer. I'd also strongly recommend using `Dictionary<>` instead of `Hashtable` - avoid non-generic collections where possible.

Comment: vmb, you're not clear about the need to write to the DeskNumber (other then from the dataReader). And should that then generate XML ?

Comment: @Jon Skeet .There is no relation between property names and xml.From db it will return this xml string starting with AdditionalInfo.So i just want find out DeskNumber from this xml string and need to assign this property to DeskNumber.

Comment: If you're only interested in "extract a particular element from some XML" then all the code to do with the database, and even the property that you want to set, is all irrelevant. There are lots of questions about parsing XML, finding a specific element (if present) and finding its value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the xml string like Format 1 with this code:

```
var xdoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(xml_string);
var xelement = xdoc.Elements("AdditionalInfo").SelectMany(x => x.Elements("Number")).FirstOrDefault();
string res = (xelement != null) ? xelement.Value : "";
```

This code returns a blank string if the `xml_string` is not in the correct format (format 1). You can use a try/catch block if you have some unknown formats.

To use this code you have some options. One is use it in the setter of the `DeskNumber` property. I recommend to define another property like `DeskNumberXml` and decorate it with `JsonProperty` attribute:

```
string _deskNumberXml;
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "u_additional_DeskNumber ")]
public string DeskNumberXml 
{ 
   get { return _deskNumberXml; }
   set
   {
      _deskNumberXml = value;
      try
      {
         var xdoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(value);
         var xelement = xdoc.Elements("AdditionalInfo").SelectMany(x => x.Elements("Number")).FirstOrDefault();
         DeskNumber = (xelement != null) ? xelement.Value : "";
      }
      catch
      {
         DeskNumber = "";
      }
   }
}

public string DeskNumber { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for ur quick response.What's the reason why we using a new property..i can use it DeskNumber set method itself..right ??..I have created a generic mapping logic to map Whatever returned from db to property names in class..In db data field will return as same name as property name .

Comment: The XDocument and especially the SelectMany are a bit overkill. You can parse the xml into an XElement and just use `e.Element("Number")?.Value ?? ""`

Comment: @vmb yes you don't need to define new property. You can use my first block of code into your mapping class. check if the property name is `DeskNumber` then apply my code.